# PHP efficiency question

Tags: php, performance

I am working on website and I am trying to make it fast as much as possible - especially the small things that can make my site a little bit quicker.

So, my to my question - I got loop that run 5 times and in each time it echo something, If I'll make variable and the loop will add the text I want to echo into the variable and just in the end I'll echo the variable - will it be faster?

loop 1 (with the echo inside the loop)

```
for ($i = 0;$i < 5;$i++)
{
    echo "test";
}
```

loop 2 (with the echo outside [when the loop finish])

```
$echostr = "";
for ($i = 0;$i < 5;$i++)
{
    $echostr .= "test";
}
echo $echostr;
```

I know that loop 2 will increase a bit the file size and therfore the user will have to download more bytes but If I got huge loop will it be better to use second loop or not?

Thanks.

Comment: _Premature optimization is the root of all evil_.

Comment: *Incomplete citations lead to almost as much evil.*

Comment: You can also optimize by using ++$i instead of $i++ to update the loop counter.  Furthermore, use single quotes instead of double quotes to surround your strings when you don't have variables in your strings (it's faster).

Comment: @John if you're that way inclined you could do `for ($i = 5; $i--;)` or even unroll the loop. All bad ideas.

Comment: @Longs Ears: I think that depends on what you're doing. In 99.999% of cases, it may be pointless optimization, but if you're working on an application in which performance is of utmost importance and you can't use a compiled language, then micro-optimization is perfectly alright. Though you should be sure that there aren't more major bottlenecks to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is negligible. Do whatever is more readable (which in this case is definitely the first case). The first approach is not a "naive" approach so there will be no major performance difference (it may actually be faster, I'm not sure). The first approach will also use less memory. Also, in many languages (not sure about PHP), appending to strings is expensive, and therefore so is concatenation (because you have to seek to the end of the string, reallocate memory, etc.).

Moreover, file size does not matter because PHP is entirely server-side -- the user never has to download your script (in fact, it would be scary if they did/could). These types of things may matter in Javascript but not in PHP.

Long story short -- don't write code constantly trying to make micro-optimizations like this. Write the code in the style that is most readable and idiomatic, test to see if performance is good, and if performance is bad *then* profile and rewrite the sections that perform poorly.

I'll end on a quote:

> "premature emphasis on efficiency is a big mistake which may well be the source of most programming complexity and grief."
>   - Donald Knuth

Comment: I prefer to make complex codes inorder to make my website faster as much as possible (I wont say anything but... google, I think thats enough).

Comment: @Ron if efficiency is such a concern, don't use PHP at all. And Google uses C++, which is where their efficiency comes from.

Comment: While the first case is definitely more *readable* given these 4 lines , it's almost certainly less *maintainable* because there's multiple points of output. The Wordpress source is a fantastic (or rather horrific) example of this.

Comment: @Long Ears perhaps in a more complex example, but this is about as simple as it can get.

Comment: The OP acknowledged that this example has been deliberately simplified and he's talking about a real website.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case of premature optimization. The performance difference is negligible.

I'd say that in general you're better off constructing a string and echoing it at the end, but because it leads to cleaner code (side effects are bad, mkay?) not because of performance.

If you optimize like this, from the ground up, you're at risk of obfuscating your code for no perceptable benefit. If you really want your script to be as fast as possible then **[profile it](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to find out where the real bottlenecks are**.

Someone else mentioned that using string concatenation instead of an immediate echo will use more memory. This isn't true unless the size of the string exceeds the size of output buffer. In any case to actually echo immediately you'd need to call `flush()` (perhaps preceded by `ob_flush()`) which adds the overhead of a function call*. The web server may still keep its own buffer which would thwart this anyway.

If you're spending *a lot* of time on each iteration of the loop then it may make sense to echo and flush early so the user isn't kept waiting for the next iteration, but that would be an entirely different question.

Also, the size of the PHP file has no effect on the user - it may take marginally longer to parse but that would be negated by using an opcode cache like APC anyway.

**To sum up**, while it may be *marginally* faster to echo each iteration, depending on circumstance, it makes the code harder to maintain (think Wordpress) and it's most likely that your time for optimization would be better spent elsewhere.

* If you're genuinely worried about this level of optimization then a function call isn't to be sniffed at. Flushing in pieces also implies extra [protocol overhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_overhead).

Answer (score 2):

The size of your PHP file does not increase the size of the download by the user. The *output* of the PHP file is all that matters to the user.

Generally, you want to do the first option: echo as soon as you have the data. Assuming you are not using output buffering, this means that the user can stream the data while your PHP script is still executing.

Answer (score 2):

The user does not download the PHP file, but only its output, so the second loop has no effect on the user's download size.

It's best not to worry about small optimizations, but instead focus on quickly delivering working software. However, if you want to improve the performance of your site, Yahoo! has done some excellent research: [developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your first example would, in theory, be fastest. Because your provided code is so extremely simplistic, I doubt any performance increase over your second example would be noticed or even useful.

In your first example the only variable PHP needs to initialize and utilize is $i.

In your second example PHP must first create an empty string variable. Then create the loop and its variable, $i. Then append the text to $echostr and then finally `echo $echostr`.

Comment: Remember to factor in the time it takes to run the "echo" call, it has to push stuff onto the stack i.e. RIP, SBP, etc. and much more.

Answer (score 0):

The code you identify as "loop 2" wouldn't be any larger of a file size for users to download.  String concatination is faster than calling a function like echo so I'd go with loop 2.  For only 5 iterations of a loop I don't think it really matters all that much.

Overall, there are a lot of other areas to focus on such as compiling PHP instead of running it as a scripted language.

http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php

Comment: as I said, my real function is much more complex than loop of 5 times. Anyway I think I'll use the loop 1 because as people answered - this will echo as soon as I have the data, it will take less memory and appending to string might be slower than echo data.